# Why is dynamic binding not faster?

Tags: c#, performance, reflection

Consider the following code:

```
delegate string StringToString(string s);

MethodInfo trimMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Trim", new Type[0]);
var trim = (StringToString)Delegate.CreateDelegate
           (typeof(StringToString), trimMethod);
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
     trim("test");
```

The above code dynamically calls string’s `Trim` method a million times without significant overhead. Now if we run the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
     "test".Trim();
```

It's faster than the first one. The first one must be faster because the costly dynamic binding happens just once.

My question is: why does the second one run faster than the first one?

Comment: How much faster is it? Do you have figures? I take it you ran each one several times to be sure.

Comment: What dynamic binding do you believe is happening in your second snippet? It's calling a non-virtual method, with no dynamic typing, no refleciton etc.

Comment: @Eraph for example execution time of the first one is 20 and the second one is 15.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks Jon, the interesting thing is that execution time of both of them are different each time I run the program.

Comment: That suggests your benchmarking could do with more work. It would simplify things if you used a method which didn't generate any garbage - garbage collector pauses may well be significant in this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets take a look at the ILCode

the first one using delegate, shows a lot of instructions to make your trim, the loop is in my eyes awful...

```
ldtoken    [mscorlib]System.String
  IL_0025:  call       class [mscorlib]System.Type [mscorlib]System.Type::GetTypeFromHandle(valuetype [mscorlib]System.RuntimeTypeHandle)
  IL_002a:  ldstr      "Trim"
  IL_002f:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0030:  newarr     [mscorlib]System.Type
  IL_0035:  call       instance class [mscorlib]System.Reflection.MethodInfo [mscorlib]System.Type::GetMethod(string,
                                                                                                              class [mscorlib]System.Type[])
  IL_003a:  stloc.1
  IL_003b:  ldtoken    ConsoleApplication1.Program/StringToString
  IL_0040:  call       class [mscorlib]System.Type [mscorlib]System.Type::GetTypeFromHandle(valuetype [mscorlib]System.RuntimeTypeHandle)
  IL_0045:  ldloc.1
  IL_0046:  call       class [mscorlib]System.Delegate [mscorlib]System.Delegate::CreateDelegate(class [mscorlib]System.Type,
                                                                                                 class [mscorlib]System.Reflection.MethodInfo)
  IL_004b:  castclass  ConsoleApplication1.Program/StringToString
  IL_0050:  stloc.2
  IL_0051:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0052:  stloc.0
  IL_0053:  br.s       IL_0065
  IL_0055:  ldloc.2                // start of loop
  IL_0056:  ldstr      "test"
  IL_005b:  callvirt   instance string ConsoleApplication1.Program/StringToString::Invoke(string)
  IL_0060:  pop
  IL_0061:  ldloc.0
  IL_0062:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_0063:  add
  IL_0064:  stloc.0
  IL_0065:  ldloc.0
  IL_0066:  ldc.i4     0xf4240
  IL_006b:  clt
  IL_006d:  stloc.3
  IL_006e:  ldloc.3
  IL_006f:  brtrue.s   IL_0055   // iterates to next trim here
```

And then the other one.

```
 IL_0001:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0002:  stloc.0
  IL_0003:  br.s       IL_0014
  IL_0005:  ldstr      "test"     // loop start
  IL_000a:  callvirt   instance string [mscorlib]System.String::Trim()
  IL_000f:  pop
  IL_0010:  ldloc.0
  IL_0011:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_0012:  add
  IL_0013:  stloc.0
  IL_0014:  ldloc.0
  IL_0015:  ldc.i4     0xf4240
  IL_001a:  clt
  IL_001c:  stloc.3
  IL_001d:  ldloc.3
  IL_001e:  brtrue.s   IL_0005   // iterate
```

the huge amount instructions for doing simple task is why the first one is slower. there are for instance four calls to functions with in the loop making it slower than the second one wich only has one call. The reason for different benchmarking is most probably your test environment that has other processes going on the same time.